# Configure Windows to use 32-bit JRE instead of 64-bit JRE

Tags: java

In my system, I have 64-bit Java 1.7 installed here: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40`

And

I have 32-bit Java 1.7 installed here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02`

When I issue `java -version` command in CMD, it shows me this:

```
C:\Users\Meraman>java -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

I want to change Java version to 32-bit.

I have tried the following:

1. Removed path to 64-bit installation from `path` variable, but still CMD shows same output for `java -version` command.
2. I have specified only 32-bit installation path in `path` variable, but still CMD shows same output for `java -version` command.
3. Then added `JAVA_HOME` variable with value `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02`, but still CMD shows same output.
4. In Java Control Panel->Java->Java Runtime Environment Settings->User, I have completed wizard to find 32-bit Java and enabled that only, with disabling 64-bit installation, but still CMD shows same output.

Please help me on this, I want to change Java to 32-bit without un-installing 64-bit.

More info:

I have restarted CMD after every changes to path or Java Control Panel.

I have `path` and `JAVA_HOME` as system variables only, no any such user variables.

**EDIT**

I have removed all java paths setting in path variable, removed JAVA_HOME variable, and still CMD shows 64-bit.

```
C:\Users\Meraman>echo %PATH%
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\Python33\;C:\Program Files (
x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system
32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.
0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files
(x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL S
erver\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;C:
\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\
Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;

C:\Users\Meraman>javac -version
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Meraman>java -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)

C:\Users\Meraman>echo %JAVA_HOME%
%JAVA_HOME%

C:\Users\Meraman>
```

**EDIT - This worked:**

Setting very first path in path variable to 32-bit java worked.

Here is output from CMD:

```
C:\Users\Meraman>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.
0\server\bin;C:\Python33\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program F
iles (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wb
em;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Techno
logies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\
Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program File
s (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL S
erver\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
 Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;

C:\Users\Meraman>javac -version
javac 1.7.0_02

C:\Users\Meraman>java -version
java version "1.7.0_02"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_02-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\Users\Meraman>echo %JAVA_HOME%
%JAVA_HOME%

C:\Users\Meraman>where java
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\java.exe
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe

C:\Users\Meraman>
```

Comment: Go to control-panel -> uninstall programs and remove the unwanted version of Java

Comment: yes that will work, but if I do not want to uninstall java 64-bit and still want to use 32-bit, how can I do that, please?

Comment: when you want to compile & run - write in the command line the full path to `javac` and `java` (in the wanted version) - never tried dual configuration like this one but I believe it should work

Comment: Changes to the system environment usually require a restart a computer, not just CMD.

Comment: @mmdw nope, open a new CMD and it should work with the updated env!

Comment: @alfasin You are right. My mistake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure to have `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin` in the PATH environment variable **before** the other paths (and in particular, before c:\windows...).

Also, make sure to restart your command line window after you've changed the PATH.

Comment: You've added the jdk's bin directory at the very beginning of the PATH, and restarted a new command line window, using Start menu - Execute - cmd.exe? What does `javac -version` display?

Comment: Yes, I have followed same steps, Path variable has set very first path as java jdk path then semicolon then other paths, then I restarted CMD, and issues java -version command, but still it shows 64-bit.

Comment: Also if I remove all java paths (64-bit and 32-bit) from path variable, CMD still able to execute java -version command and shows 64-bit.

Comment: I have removed JAVA_HOME variable, and removed 32-bit and 64-bit paths from path variable, then restarted CMD, but still CMD able to execute java -version command, and shows 64-bit. I doubt java may set registry settings for path, and I dont know how to update that :(

Comment: Edit your question and add the following information: output of `echo %PATH%`, output of `javac -version`, output of `java -version`

Comment: And output of `where java` may be useful too.

Comment: Look at your output of echo %PATH%. There's no JDK path in there. Nowhere.

Comment: When first I tried setting first path to java 32-bit, I forgot to put \bin directory in java path. Now I have complete path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin) very first path in path variable, and it is working :)

Comment: +1, thank you very much, it worked. I suspect java.exe in C:\Windows\System32 doing something. :)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem!

Please look into C:\Windows\System32...

you will find a java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe digital signed by Oracle America, Inc.

Because PATH includes C:\Windows\system32 at the beginning, windows will find this java.exe before your 32 bit java.exe

Timm from Hamburg (Germany)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the same files (java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe) at:

```
 C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

Answer (score 0):

on our estate we have the latest Java 8 x86 and x64 installed. Experienced the same problem above
PATH was referencing C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath

Changing the path above to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_*xxx*\bin  resolved the problem