# Java - Getting a project to run with JPcap

Tags: java, eclipse, winpcap, jpcap

I'm trying to set up a project that uses jpcap in order to detect network traffic. I've tried various ways to get it to work, however every way ends up in errors. I run windows 64 bit, but here's what I've done:

- Installed winpcap
- Installed jpcap
- Copied jpcap.dll to the JRE directory (program files/JRE AND program files (x86)/JRE)
- Copied jpcap.jar to the JRE directory/lib/ext
- Copied jpcap.jar to the JDK directory

After doing all that, I add the jpcap.jar to my build path. When I try to compile a simple line, I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jpcap.JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList()[Ljpcap/NetworkInterface;

In the other version of eclipse, I get a different error, following the same steps:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\jpcap.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

The line of code I'm using in both cases is:

```
 list = JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList();
```

Any help to get this working would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113080/cant-load-ia-32-bit-dll-on-a-amd-64-bit-platform)

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, you'll have to recompile the DLL for 64-bit. Your only other
>   option is to switch to a 32-bit JVM, or otherwise get some 32-bit
>   process to load the DLL on your behalf and communicate with that
>   process somehow.

extracted from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113080/cant-load-ia-32-bit-dll-on-a-amd-64-bit-platform)

Comment: I have both java 32 and java 64 bit. How do I select it to run java 32 bit?

Comment: Read on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450859/change-64-bit-java-to-32-bit-java

Comment: I've tried changing the version of java it runs, but it still gives the same errors?